# How to fix code runner that executes the program slowly on windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

[image]

months before it worked as fast as I click the run
now it does now do the same

I have already contacted vs code and asked they said that it is the code runner

here is the link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171501

and I have already tried to reinstall the vscode cleanly
also tried disabling the extensions and so on

Comment: why use code runner, there is no need to use it, use tasks and launch configs

Comment: @rioV8 ahmm how do I do that?
I am new to vs code

Comment: Can you try executing `measure-command { gcc Untitled-1.c -o Untitled-1.exe | out-default }` to measure how long it takes `gcc` to compile the program? And can you check if it's windows update or windows defender's real-time protection slowing down your command?

Comment: there are a lot of doc paged for VSC, and for specific languages even more pages

Comment: @SimonSmith

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 406
Ticks             : 4068600
TotalDays         : 4.70902777777778E-06
TotalHours        : 0.000113016666666667
TotalMinutes      : 0.006781
TotalSeconds      : 0.40686
TotalMilliseconds : 406.86

Comment: windows update is also paused 
windwows defender scanning is also off

Comment: @DaveBalanghig On my laptop, it takes ~170 milliseconds to compile the same source code. But I'd say 400 milliseconds are bearable... Did you try repeating the command coder runner has executed? Is it slow because of code runner or just your environment setup?

Comment: @SimonSmith I copied your code and run it  " measure-command { gcc Untitled-1.c -o Untitled-1.exe | out-default } "

and the environmental variable  is on system and user

with the same path ( MinGW)

Comment: @DaveBalanghig https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251297/issue-code-runner-executes-slowly-in-vs-code Could you enter the chat room so I can better assist you? The discussion in the comments area is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Disable any anti-virus
I thought defender slowed my vs. code but all anti virus does that
for which, in my case, I disabled Avira